# Modificar una URL en un sumit sin perder el page_id Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Tengo un website y en él unas funciones que recopilan unos datos para después enviarlos a una URL con un submit, el html es el siguiente:

```
<span class="nearest"; style="color: white; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold">
  <form action="http://example.com/?page_id=262" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Solicitar" name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" class="btn btn-primary "style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">
  </form>
</span>
<br>
```

Como es Wordpress, quisiera que todo el contenido se fuera a un contact form en la página http://example.com/?page_id=262. Por eso necesito que cuando la gente dé click en "Solicitar", el submit reenvíe a otra URL que debería quedar así:

```
http://example.com/?page_id=262&5value1=precio&5value2=ciudad
```

Sin embargo me queda así:

```
http://example.com/?5value1=precio&5value2=ciudad.
```

Es decir, estoy perdiendo el page_id=262&.

¿Tienen idea de cómo resolver esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás perdiendo `page_id=262&` porque esta parte de la URL original es una variable GET. Para poder re-crear la solicitud con el mismo parámetro, deberás incluir una etiqueta INPUT oculta:

```
<input type="hidden" value="262" name="page_id">
```

Colócala inmediatamente después de la etiqueta `<form ... >` para obtener la URL que deseas.